# Does Typescript offer an equivalent to Kotlin's "when()"?

Tags: typescript, expression

Kotlin has a nice alternative to lengthy "if() else if () else if() ..." blocks in the form of the `when()` expression. Does Typescript offer something similar?

Comment: [`switch`/ `case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), FYI this is JS not typescript.

Comment: There is no `when`-like pattern matching (as in, from functional programming languages) in javascript. You can do conditional value matching with `switch` but that's about it.

Comment: @Chase Thanks. I did not find anything on the web but sometimes it's just because you are using the wrong search terms ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯